# How can I do a select or update query in MS Access to get the position or rank of a league?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am building a competition with a classification where I need to calculate the position of each player in the following way:

```
Position   Players       Points
1          Player1       10
1          Player2       10
1          Player3       10
4          Player4       8
5          Player5       7
5          Player6       7
7          Player7       5
```

.....

Is possible to do that in an update sql query or in a select query?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you using a specific Database system or you want pure SQL request ?
I think in most of them you can use the RANK() function.

Comment: Yes... I didn't say that database is a MS Access...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Rank()--using sqlserver

```
SELECT *,  RANK ()  OVER( ORDER BY points desc) AS Position
FROM yourtable
```

if you are using ms-access try below

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT COUNT(T1.points) 
          FROM
                 [Table] AS T1 
         WHERE T1.points>= T2.points) AS Rank 
FROM 
      [Table] AS T2 
ORDER BY points DESC
```

Comment: My database is Access and Rank doesn't exist there

Answer (score 0):

To get it in the order asked for you need to include *desc* in the query

```
CREATE TABLE #league 
( position int, players varchar(50), points int)


insert into #league  select 1, 'Player1', 10
insert into #league  select 1, 'Player2', 10
insert into #league  select 1, 'Player3', 10
insert into #league  select 4, 'Player4', 8
insert into #league  select 5, 'Player5', 7
insert into #league  select 5, 'Player6', 7
insert into #league  select 7, 'Player7', 5

SELECT *,  RANK ()  OVER( ORDER BY points desc) AS Position
FROM #league

DROP TABLE #LEAGUE
```